# Git Aptana integration in remote file explorer

Tags: git, aptana

Aptana provides Git integrations (Right click > Team) only if a git project is checked out into my local filesystem. This doesn't happen if I am working on a Git repository hosted on a remote server.. I know it is less than ideal to work on a remote repository but is there a way to have Aptana recognize remote git repositories and have the git commands enabled for them as well?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? I'm trying to get Aptana to play nicely with auto-sychnronizing and git with a remote file system, as well. Not having much luck.

Comment: @JasonMcClellan unfortunately no.. we commit stuff in the remote repo using the command terminal now - Aptana doesnt seem to recognize remote repositories... I will update if I get anywhere with this... thanks